# Why does MatConvNet say that data and derivatives don't have matching formats?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

**Problem Statement**

I was using MatConvNet to build a very simple 1D example and small network using the function cnn_train that comes with the examples library. Following their example I built a small CNN example as follows:

```
    clc;clear;clc;clear;
%% prepare Data
M = 32; %batch size
X_train = zeros(1,1,1,M); % (1 1 1 2) = (1 1 1 M)
for m=1:M,
    X_train(:,:,:,m) = m; %training example value
end
Y_test = 10*X_train;
split = ones(1,M);
split(floor(M*0.75):end) = 2;
% load image dadabase (imgdb)
imdb.images.data = X_train;
imdb.images.label = Y_test;
imdb.images.set = split;
%% prepare parameters
L1=3;
w1 = randn(1,1,1,L1); %1st layer weights
w2 = randn(1,1,1,L1); %2nd layer weights
b1 = randn(1,1,1,L1); %1st layer biases
b2 = randn(1,1,1,L1); %2nd layer biases
G1 = ones(1,1,1,L1); % (1 1 1 3) = (1 1 1 L1) BN scale, one per  dimension
B1 = zeros(1,1,1,L1); % (1 1 1 3) = (1 1 1 L1) BN shift, one per  dimension
EPS = 1e-4;
%% make CNN layers: conv, BN, relu, conv, pdist, l2-loss
net.layers = {} ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', ...
                           'name', 'conv1', ...
                           'weights', {{w1, b1}}, ...
                           'pad', 0) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'bnorm', ...
                           'weights', {{G1, B1}}, ...
                           'EPSILON', EPS, ...
                           'learningRate', [1 1 0.05], ...
                           'weightDecay', [0 0]) ;                       
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'relu', ...
                           'name', 'relu1' ) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', ...
                           'name', 'conv2', ...
                           'weights', {{w2, b2}}, ...
                           'pad', 0) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'pdist', ...
                           'name', 'averageing1', ...
                           'class', 0, ...
                           'p', 1) ;
%% add L2-loss                   
fwfun = @l2LossForward;
bwfun = @l2LossBackward;
net = addCustomLossLayer(net, fwfun, bwfun) ;
net.layers{end}.class = Y_test; % its the test set
net = vl_simplenn_tidy(net) ;
res = vl_simplenn(net, X_train);
%% prepare train options
trainOpts.expDir = 'results/' ; %save results/trained cnn
trainOpts.gpus = [] ;
trainOpts.batchSize = 2 ;
trainOpts.learningRate = 0.02 ;
trainOpts.plotDiagnostics = false ;
%trainOpts.plotDiagnostics = true ; % Uncomment to plot diagnostics
trainOpts.numEpochs = 20 ; % number of training epochs
trainOpts.errorFunction = 'none' ;
%% CNN TRAIN
vl_simplenn_display(net) ;
net = cnn_train(net, imdb, @getBatch, trainOpts) ;
```

I created this according to [the example they provided](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/practicals/cnn-reg/index.html), whenever I run the example I get the error:

```
Error using vl_nnconv
DATA and DEROUTPUT do not have compatible formats.

Error in vl_simplenn (line 397)
          [res(i).dzdx, dzdw{1}, dzdw{2}] = vl_nnconv(res(i).x, l.weights{1},
          l.weights{2}, res(i+1).dzdx)

Error in cnn_train>process_epoch (line 323)
    res = vl_simplenn(net, im, dzdy, res, ...

Error in cnn_train (line 139)
    [net,stats.train,prof] = process_epoch(opts, getBatch, epoch, train, learningRate,
    imdb, net) ;

Error in main_1D_1layer_hard_coded_example (line 64)
net = cnn_train(net, imdb, @getBatch, trainOpts) ;
```

does someone know what is going on? The example is actually suppose to be simple so its confusing me what might be wrong.

---

**SUPPLEMENTARY SECTION OF THINGS I'VE TRIED TO SOLVE THIS**.

For more details of things I tried to solve this read ahead.

I went to that line in the file causing the error and printed the inputs to that function to make sure that I was giving arguments that made sense and its seems all is fine with that respect:

```
  case 'conv'
      size(res(i).x)
      size(res(i+1).dzdx)
      size(l.weights{1})
      size(l.weights{2})
      [res(i).dzdx, dzdw{1}, dzdw{2}] = vl_nnconv(res(i).x, l.weights{1}, l.weights{2}, res(i+1).dzdx)
    [res(i).dzdx, dzdw{1}, dzdw{2}] = ...
      vl_nnconv(res(i).x, l.weights{1}, l.weights{2}, res(i+1).dzdx, ...
      'pad', l.pad, ...
      'stride', l.stride, ...
      l.opts{:}, ...
      cudnn{:}) ;
```

prints:

```
ans =

     1     1     3    16


ans =

     1     1     3    16


ans =

     1     1     1     3


ans =

     1     1     1     3
```

what I expected.

I even went ahead and manually hard coded what the chain of derivatives the network should be computing and that file seems to work fine:

```
clc;clear;clc;clear;
%% prepare Data
M = 3;
x = zeros(1,1,1,M); % (1 1 1 2) = (1 1 1 M)
for m=1:M,
    x(:,:,:,m) = m;
end
Y = 5;
r=Y;
%% parameters
L1 = 3;
w1 = randn(1,1,1,L1); % (1 1 1 L1) = (1 1 1 3)
b1 = ones(1,L1);
w2 = randn(1,1,1,L1); % (1 1 1 L1) = (1 1 1 3)
b2 = ones(1,L1);
G1 = ones(1,1,1,L1); % (1 1 1 3) = (1 1 1 L1) BN scale, one per  dimension
B1 = zeros(1,1,1,L1); % (1 1 1 3) = (1 1 1 L1) BN shift, one per  dimension
EPS = 1e-4;
%% Forward Pass
z1 = vl_nnconv(x,w1,b1); % (1 1 3 2) = (1 1 L1 M)
%bn1 = z1;
bn1 = vl_nnbnorm(z1,G1,B1,'EPSILON',EPS); % (1 1 3 2) = (1 1 L1 M)
a1 = vl_nnrelu(bn1); % (1 1 3 2) = (1 1 L1 M) 
z2 = vl_nnconv(a1,w2,b2);
y1 = vl_nnpdist(z2, 0, 1);
loss_forward = l2LossForward(y1,Y);
%%
net.layers = {} ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', ...
                           'name', 'conv1', ...
                           'weights', {{w1, b1}}, ...
                           'pad', 0) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'bnorm', ...
                           'weights', {{G1, B1}}, ...
                           'EPSILON', EPS, ...
                           'learningRate', [1 1 0.05], ...
                           'weightDecay', [0 0]) ;                       
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'relu', ...
                           'name', 'relu1' ) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', ...
                           'name', 'conv2', ...
                           'weights', {{w2, b2}}, ...
                           'pad', 0) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'pdist', ...
                           'name', 'averageing1', ...
                           'class', 0, ...
                           'p', 1) ;
fwfun = @l2LossForward;
bwfun = @l2LossBackward;
net = addCustomLossLayer(net, fwfun, bwfun) ;
net.layers{end}.class = Y;
net = vl_simplenn_tidy(net) ;
res = vl_simplenn(net, x);
%%
loss_forward = squeeze( loss_forward ) % (1 1)
loss_res = squeeze( res(end).x ) % (1 1)
%% Backward Pass
p = 1;
dldx = l2LossBackward(y1,r,p);
dy1dx = vl_nnpdist(z2, 0, 1, dldx);
[dz2dx, dz2dw2] = vl_nnconv(a1, w2, b2, dy1dx);
da1dx = vl_nnrelu(bn1, dz2dx);
[dbn1dx,dbn1dG1,dbn1dB1] = vl_nnbnorm(z1,G1,B1,da1dx);
[dz1dx, dz1dw1] = vl_nnconv(x, w1, b1, dbn1dx);
%%
dzdy = 1;
res = vl_simplenn(net, x, dzdy, res);
%%
% func = @(x) proj(p, forward(x, x0)) ;
% err = checkDerivativeNumerically(f, x, dx)
% %%
dz1dx = squeeze(dz1dx)
dz1dx_vl_simplenn = squeeze(res(1).dzdx)
```

The derivatives seem to math so I'd assume that everything in that file works. It doesn't throw an error, so the fact that it doesn't even run has me very confused. Anyone know whats going on?

---

The way I loaded my CNN was based on [the example file](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/practicals/cnn-reg/index.html) they provide on that tutorial. I will paste a summary of the important aspects of that file (that runs fine with cnn_train function while mine does not).

```
setup() ;
% setup('useGpu', true); % Uncomment to initialise with a GPU support
%% Part 3.1: Prepare the data
% Load a database of blurred images to train from
imdb = load('data/text_imdb.mat') ;

%% Part 3.2: Create a network architecture

net = initializeSmallCNN() ;
%net = initializeLargeCNN() ;
% Display network
vl_simplenn_display(net) ;

%% Part 3.3: learn the model
% Add a loss (using a custom layer)
net = addCustomLossLayer(net, @l2LossForward, @l2LossBackward) ;

% Train
trainOpts.expDir = 'data/text-small' ;
trainOpts.gpus = [] ;
% Uncomment for GPU training:
%trainOpts.expDir = 'data/text-small-gpu' ;
%trainOpts.gpus = [1] ;
trainOpts.batchSize = 16 ;
trainOpts.learningRate = 0.02 ;
trainOpts.plotDiagnostics = false ;
%trainOpts.plotDiagnostics = true ; % Uncomment to plot diagnostics
trainOpts.numEpochs = 20 ;
trainOpts.errorFunction = 'none' ;

net = cnn_train(net, imdb, @getBatch, trainOpts) ;
```

Comment: Can you come up with an example that is less.... *non*-minimal?

Comment: @AndrasDeak sure, do you mean its to complicated? Its suppose to be a simple network and I just provided some of the things I've tried to fix it.

Comment: I tried commenting the example more to make it convincing that its very simple. Hope it helps.

Comment: You should simplify your example, it is too long and I would need an hour just to read what you wrote. Providing a shorter example will increase the amount of answers and will give you the chance to find the problem yourself.

Comment: Did you solve this problem @Pinocchio?

Comment: @AtenaNguyen  its been to long ago, I don't remember. I probably did considering I awarded the bounty to someone.

Answer (score 3):

The dimensions of w2 should be 1x1x3x3.

Also usually the biases would be given as 1x3, since they only have one dimension (or 1x1x3xN for the weights and 1xN for the corresponding biases, where N is the number of filters), and the same is true for B1 and G1 (here it is 1xM, where M is the number of filters in the previous layer). But it might work either way.

In your example the dimensions of x are 1x1x3x16 after the first convolution. This means there are 16 elements in one batch where each element has width and height 1 and depth 3. Depth 3 because the first convolution was done with 3 filters (w1 has dimensions 1x1x1x3).

w2 in your example has dimensions 1x1x1x3, which denotes 3 filters of width, height and depth 1. So the depth of the filters doesn't match the depth of the input.

Comment: Two comments, 1) I did make w2 1x1x3x3 but it still didn't run unfortunately.  2) your reasoning makes sense in a logical sense, but the thing that still baffles me is that, if your argument was correct then why can I successfully run a forward pass in the model? If you notice in the code I gave there is the line `res = vl_simplenn(net, X_train);` which evaluates the model and to my surprise actually runs. If there was a mismatch of dimensions, then why does the forward pass even run?

I don't know yet but it seems that the back-pass is the problem from the error output. I will try to check.

Comment: I must have overlooked that. That's strange. Maybe I'll have time over the next few days to try your code myself.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem by creating a custom layer. I finally found the solution for it by tracking the matconvnet implementation. Hope it will help other later.

In short, you need to make sure the two data are not empty, not null, and have same device type (GPU or CPU) and same data type (float, single or char).

In my case, both data have to have same 'gpuArray' and 'single'.

====== Details ==================
Firstly, the error

> DATA and FILTERS do not have compatible formats
>
> DATA and BIASES do not have compatible formats
>
> DATA and DEROUTPUT do not have compatible formats

exactly say that the two variables do not have compatible formats.
So what Matconvnet mean 'compatible formats'?
It is implemented in vl_nnconv.cu, line 269~278

```
 /* check for GPU/data class consistency */


if (hasFilters && ! vl::areCompatible(data, filters)) {
    vlmxError(VLMXE_IllegalArgument, "DATA and FILTERS do not have compatible formats.") ;
  }
  if (hasBiases && ! vl::areCompatible(data, biases)) {
    vlmxError(VLMXE_IllegalArgument, "DATA and BIASES do not have compatible formats.") ;
  }
  if (backMode && ! vl::areCompatible(data, derOutput)) {
    vlmxError(VLMXE_IllegalArgument, "DATA and DEROUTPUT do not have compatible formats.") ;
  }
```

The error come from function vl::areCompatible which is implemented as

```
inline bool areCompatible(Tensor const & a, Tensor const & b)
  {
    return
    (a.isEmpty() || a.isNull()) ||
    (b.isEmpty() || b.isNull()) ||
    ((a.getDeviceType() == b.getDeviceType()) & (a.getDataType() == b.getDataType())) ;
  }
```

So, basically, it checks whether any input is empty or null and makes sure both inputs have the same data type (double, single, vs char) and device type (GPU, CPU).

```
 /// Type of device: CPU or GPU
  enum DeviceType {
    VLDT_CPU = 0,
    VLDT_GPU
  }  ;

  /// Type of data (char, float, double, ...)
  enum DataType {
    VLDT_Char,
    VLDT_Float,
    VLDT_Double
  } ;
```